# Should I call Cef.Shutdown() when shutdownOnProcessExit is set to true?

Tags: cefsharp

I'm initializing Cef as following
    `var cefSettings = new CefSettings {LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Disable};
    Cef.Initialize(cefSettings, shutdownOnProcessExit: true);`

I've noticed that if I don't explicitly call `Cef.Shutdown()` on my app exit it doesn't exit properly, and `CefSharp.BrowserSuprocess.exe` remains running.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't `Cef.Shutdown()` be called implicitly in this case?

I'm using CefSharp build 45 (and about to upgrade to 47)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format the inline code - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also trimmed 'thanks' and the signature, these are not used in SO by custom. Please edit the question and provide any additional details necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Does your application shut down normally? Or you shut it down by killing the process (or clicking "Stop Debugging (Shift+F5)" in VS)?

Comment: It shuts down normally. When I call Cef.Shutdown() on App_OnExit() everything works fine, but if I omit this call the application hangs. I built and debugged CefSharp and saw that Cef.Shutdown() is being implicitly called by after it returns my application doesn't exit

Comment: I continue debugging and found out the following - when I call Cef.Shutdown() from App_OnExit(), the call is done on the main application thread. When the call is done implicitly by Cef, it's running on a worker thread. My application is a WPF app.

Comment: It's a best attempt to shutdown, code is shared between the three variants, so it makes no special considerations for `WPF`. It's also safe to call `Cef.Shutdown` multiple times, subsequent calls will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly call Cef.Shutdown() from the main thread(mostly UI) before you exit your application

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/800#issuecomment-83198945

Cef runs as a sub-process, and has to be notified before you exit your application.

[some tips on shutdown](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#application-freezing-on-shutdown)